# How to override payment page place order button in Magento 2.2.x?

Tags: magento2.2

I need to disable 'Place Order' button on payment page based on logged customer group data. I see following in one of the payment method's template HTML file.

Any idea on which block or helper need to be overwritten to add custom code and call that method in the html file?
I overwrote cc_form.html file in custom module using requiresjs-config.js and it's working but need information on getting customer data into the template.

I would like to do this in custom module, don't want to update out of box code.

```
<button data-role="review-save"
    type="submit"
    data-bind="
    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
    enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
    click: placeOrder,
    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
    "
    class="action primary checkout"
    disabled>
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
```